# My jqwidgets grid isn't being displayed on my page

Tags: jquery

I'm working on a jqwidgets grid for a site but I can't get it to display on the page.

Here is the code I used:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqxcore.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqxbuttons.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqxscrollbar.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqxmenu.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqxcheckbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqxlistbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqxdropdownlist.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqxgrid.js"></script>
<script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // prepare the data
        var source =
        {
            datatype: "json",
            datafields: [
                { name: 'Username', type: 'string'},
                { name: 'First_name', type: 'string'},
                { name: 'Surname', type: 'string'},
                { name: 'Email', type: 'string'}
            ],
            url: 'data.php',
            cache: false
        };

            var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source);

        $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid(
        {
            source: dataAdapter,
            theme: 'classic',
            columns: [
              { text: 'Username', datafield: 'Username', width: 250},
              { text: 'First Name', datafield: 'First_name', width: 150 },
              { text: 'Surname', datafield: 'Surname', width: 180 },
              { text: 'Email Address', datafield: 'Email', width: 200 }
          ]
        });        
    });
</script>
```

Any help you could give would be welcome. I have been trying to sort it or something similar out myself all day without much luck.

Answer (score 0):

That's actually just a part of the code  that is required. You should probably have HTML part as well. Could you post it, too? You can also check this topic [jquery-grid-getting-started.htm](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-documentation/documentation/jqxgrid/jquery-grid-getting-started.htm) out

Comment: <body>

<div id=’jqxWidget’ style=”font-size: 12px; font-family: Verdana; float: left;”>

<div id=”jqxgrid”>

</div>

</div>

</body>

Comment: It should be probably something like: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>Your Scripts</head><body><div id="jqxgrid"></div></body></html>

Comment: Changed that still no luck, any idea what the problem might be. I connect to my database without any problems.

Comment: Reference to jqxdata.js is missing, too

Comment: added reference, no improvement

Comment: I suggest you to look any of the help topics or the online samples on the jqwidgets website and also to turn on your browser's debugger as it should display some messages in the console.

Answer (score -1):

There is an extra script tag ( unclosed ) 
or 
Manually open url ( data.php is above case) and check if data is properly loaded . use jsoneditoronline.org to check of returned text is valid json data.